# Ubuntu installation from Windows installer failed

Tags: system-installation

I tried installing Ubuntu through the Windows installer provided so that I can have a dual boot system ( Windows as well as Ubuntu ). I changed the drive to E as Windows system files were in C. But the installation failed due to an exception with the following message :

Exception: Could not retrieve the required disk image files

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem and after I changed web proxy, windows installer worked fine so I'm sure it's network problem. The interesting thing is I could access internet and even could download ubuntu iso but wubi. exe didn't work before I change proxy. So I spent a long time to figure out it was network issue.

Or download iso separately and put wubi.exe and iso into same folder also can fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu Windows installer - Wubi, will download the Ubuntu ISO to the disk and then start installation. The exception message seems to indicate that it could not do so, did you check your internet connection?

You can also download the ISO manually and place it in the same folder as the Wubi.exe file. Wubi will then use that ISO to install Ubuntu on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

I also spent a long time to figure out it was the network issue.That way can solve this problem:

1. Download ubuntu-12.04.3-wubi-i386.tar.xz
2. Open `cmd` and than come in the file of wubi.exe
3. Type `wubi.exe --dimagepath=f:\ubuntu-12.04.1-wubi-i386.tar.xz`

Comment: Don't recommend the use of wubi!

Comment: why?something wrong?

Comment: Wubi is unsupported in newer releases, and give lots of headaches to the users. Right now the recommended path is partitioning the Hard Drive and install Ubuntu in a separated partition.